# Unique unordered combinations of varying length

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given random set of integers. I.e.

$\{1,2,2,3,3,3,5\}$

Find the number of **unique, unordered** *of varying length* sets that can be created.

---

### My Workings

---

This is *not* a homework problem, but rather, I'm trying to develop an algorithm to calculate the number of divisors a number has after knowing  all of its factors. For example, 36 has

$$1*36$$
$$2*18$$
$$3*12$$
$$4*9$$
$$6*6$$
A total of **9** *unique* divisors.

I have broken this problem down in the the above description, but I haven't been able to consolidate everything.

My approach is to consider every unordered combination, and then remove the duplicates.

I begin by not considering the 1 since it will not give additional divisors (I just add 2 in the end).

$\{2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5\}$

Let $L$ be length $= 6$

#### Consolidating Varying Length

I approach this by considering each length from $n$ to $L$ separately.

Groups of $n$ Where $ 1<= n <=L$

$L\choose{n}$ $=\frac{L!}{n!(L-n)!}$

This would give the number of unordered combinations for a given length $n$.

#### Consolidating Repeated Factors

Now I consider each subset of repeated integers $\{2,2\}$ $\{3,3,3\}$

For the set of length 3 the duplicates will be found as follows:

1. $\underline{R}\space \underline{U} \space \underline{U}$
2. $\underline{R}\space \underline{R} \space \underline{U}$
3. $\underline{R}\space \underline{R} \space \underline{R}$

Where $R$ is an unordered subset of a duplicate set $\{3, 3\}  \{2\}$ and $U$ is an unordered subset of the unique set $\{2, 3, 5\}$

So, for 1. if I'm considering the duplicate set $\{3,3\}$ I would remove the amount equal to: $2\choose{1}$ $*$$3\choose{2}$

For 2. It would be $2\choose{2}$ $*$$3\choose{1}$

Then for 3. I wouldn't subtract anything for the subset of $\{3,3\}$ since it's not long enough.

---

### Roadblock

---

Using this method, I've been able to predict the divisor count of *some* numbers, though my brain is mushy right now and I could have mistakes I don't realize.

1. Is there any easier way to do this?
2. Why doesn't my method work for all cases? Like if the factors were: $\{1, 2, 2, 2, 2\}$

Comment: If the prime power factorization is $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes then the number of divisors is $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_n+1)$.

Comment: I'm in horror right now. Please tell me it is not that simple. Could you give me more information to go off of?

Comment: It is that simple. For $36=2^23^2$ it is (2+1)(2+1)$. The proof of the general case is straightforward.

Comment: But that yields 12, not 9? I'm looking for the number of unique divisors, perhaps I am using the wrong terminology.

Comment: Yes I see your edit. I'm in awe because I spent a lot of time on this. Would you happen to know a resource for a rigorous proof? I am very interested in seeing it.

Comment: @Klik:  No, that gives $9$.  Another example that avoids the common power of $2$ is $360=2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5$ has $(3+1)(2+1)(1+1)=24$ different factors.  The idea is that you can have from $0$ to $3$ factors of $2$, from $0$ to $2$ factors of $3$, and either $0$ or $1$ factor of $5$.  You multiply the number of choices for each factor.

Comment: To make a factor $w$ of $n$ we decide how many $p_1$'s it will have, $0$ to $a_1$, so $a_1+1$ choices. For every one of these choices, there are $a_2+1$ ways to decide how many $p_2$'s $w$ will have, and so on.

Comment: To construct a divisor you need to decide how many p_1s it has, and you have a_1+1 choices, from zero to a_1; then how many p_2s, and you have a_2+1 choices, and so on.

Comment: Great minds think alike, I guess ;-)

Comment: It is amazing how a slightly different approach can enormously simplify a problem. Hah! I will never forget this. Cheers.